# CSS clip-path to clip a png

Tags: css, clip, clip-path

I'm very new to code and I am desperately trying to test out clip-path. I've searched high and low for a simple tutorial or sample code and nothing seems to have any effect. I feel I must be missing something very simple. Here's the code so far:

HTML:

```
<body>
<img class="image" src=#imagepath>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  width: 450px;
  height: 600px;  
  clip-path: rectangle(20px, 175px, 50px, 175px);
}
```

Is there a specific library I'm missing? Is my syntax incorrect?

Here is a link to my codepen:
http://codepen.io/tlipchen/pen/gwrGbQ

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: make sure you're whatever browser you're using has support for `clip-path` first. I believe this is still listed as experimental, and may not be supported in what you're using: http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: Excellent info thanks! I'm using Chrome, and it seems to be supported...